# Chmod 600 issue

Tags: login, chmod

My situation is I was using terminal for ssh did the `chmod 600 /` then I did the `~`. Stopped me from going into files rebooted and stuck atlogin screen where type password blink black screen then login again.

I have checked `la -la` and the changes I see are:

```
Drwxr-xr-x 22 root root 4620 dev.
Dr-xr-xr-x 205 root root 0 proc
Drwxr-xr-x 31 root root 900 run.
Dr-xr-xr-x 13 root root 0 says
Drwxrwxrwt 14 root root 4096 tmp
```

Comment: Copy/paste the actual input and output from your terminal [into your Question](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1269036/edit) instead of descriptions, please. ([Formatting help](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help))

Comment: Boot with a live USB to get list of what permissions should look like. If you didn't use `-r` it should be a quick fix.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem might have been that if chmod 600 gives the owner Read/Write privileges, and the home directory might have needed execution permissions. Try using chmod 755 to restore execution permissions.

Comment: Thanks guys just did a reinstall but was fun trying to figure it out. And your responses were great

Answer (score 0):

did you run

```
chmod 600 -Rf /
```

with root privileges?
if so i would recommend to reinstall.

if you did run it as user try logging in as root or use recovery mode (press shift on boot in the moment where grub is loaded) and create a new user, move the needet user files and chown them.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to change previous permission. If you gave `chmod 600 /`, there is no way to revert.

Answer (score 0):

You have made a big mess. Now the best fix is to reinstall Ubuntu. Or if you don't want to reinstall Ubuntu then boot into live CD and do as instructed (dangerous):

1. Mount root partition and other partitions relatively.
2. Open Terminal.
3. Execute the following command:

```bsh
sudo mv /var/lib/dpkg/status{,.backup}
```

2. Copy the `status` file:

```bsh
sudo cp <mountpoint-of-installed-ubuntu>/var/lib/dpkg/status /var/lib/dpkg/status
```

3. Clean `apt` cache with this:

```bsh
sudo apt clean
```

4. Download all installed packages:

```bsh
sudo apt list --installed | sed 's/\// /' | awk '/\[installed\]/{print $1}' | sudo xargs apt install --reinstall -dy
```

5. Reinstall all packages:

```bsh
sudo dpkg -i --root <mountpoint-of-installed-ubuntu> /var/cache/apt/archives/*.deb
```

6. `chroot` into your system:

```bsh
sudo chroot <mountpoint-of-installed-ubuntu>
```

7. Add new user with `sudo` permission:

```bsh
sudo adduser <username>
sudo usermod -aG sudo <username>
```

After you successfully done all above, restart into your installed Ubuntu. If it boots successfully, try to login with old user. If it logins successfully then fix file permissions one by one inside your home directory (directories must have executable permissions). If login fails then continue with the new user and fix file permissions one by one inside your previous home directory.

If above fails then you have to do nothing but reinstalling Ubuntu.

Comment: Definitely a big mess but a learning experience. Looking to get a cheap system to keep playing around with only way to get Better is to try things. Want to one day be able to be like you guys and help others like gurus thanks all much appreciation

Comment: @Striderkiba You can just create Virtual Machine with QEMU or VirtualBox. Inside that VM you can do anything.